# Contact Form Not Working On Site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contact-form

I am having a problem getting a contact form on my site to work!

[Page link.](http://bpcs.com/test/index-4.html)

Here is the HTML

```
<form id="contact-form">
                        <div class="success"> Contact form submitted! <strong>We will be in touch soon.</strong></div>
                        <fieldset>
                            <label class="name">
                                <input type="text" value="Enter Your Name:">
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid name.</span>
                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="email">
                                <input type="text" value="Enter Your E-mail:">
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid email address.</span>
                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="phone">
                                <input type="text" value="Enter Your Phone:">
                                <span class="error">*This is not a valid phone number.</span>
                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                            </label>
                            <label class="message">
                                <textarea>Enter Your Message:</textarea>
                                <span class="error">*The message is too short.</span>
                                <span class="empty">*This field is required.</span>
                                <span class="clear"></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="buttons"><strong><a class="button" data-type="reset">Reset<span></span></a></strong><strong><a class="button" data-type="submit">Submit<span></span></a></strong></div>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
```

Here is the Javascript up top!

```
$(function(){
$('#contact-form').forms({ownerEmail:'brandon@kizukatech.com'}) 
});
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: @BillGregg -- ooh, ooh, I know, I know!  "It's not working"

Comment: Problem is it is not submitting the information to my email.

Comment: @BillGregg The OP stated clearly in the original post what his problem is: the completed form is not being emailed. Just because he doesn't know how to do it is no reason for condescension or (hello LittleBobbyTables) ridicule.

Answer (score 1):

For the contact form to work, the data entered between `<form>` and `</form>` must be sent somewhere. This is done through the `action=` form parameter, such as:

```
<form id="contactform" action="fireaway.php">
    //All your form fields go here
</form>
```

THEN, you must have a `fireaway.php` file on your webserver that actually does the processing. It receives that values of all variables POSTed by the contact form, constructs the email, and sends the email.

Perhaps [this site](http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php) has what you need.

Comment: Cool I do have something called mailhandler.php I tried doing the action to it and it didn't work. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't include an action, so submitting the form does nothing.  Try this:

```
<form id="contact-form" action="YOUR_SERVER_SIDE_PAGE" method="post">
```

Comment: Good catch :) question is not clear

Comment: What does Your_server_side_page mean? I tried that and it didn't work.